# SELECT command denied to user cannot connect to database

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver

I have uploaded my website to an add on domain, given the user "tomzino1_user1" the correct privileges and added the user to the correct database. It is a php based website written on Dreamweaver

When I attempt to access my site (theboatshedmusic.com) it comes up with the error message:

```
SELECT command denied to user 'tomzino1_user1'@'localhost' for table 'main_table'
```

The hosting company's support service checked that the tables were responding correctly and that the user had been given the correct privileges and added to the config file correctly. They suggested there was a problem with the scripts which were working fine with my MAMP testing database.

The config file reads as:

```
<?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_boatshed = "localhost";
$database_boatshed = "tomzino1_boatshed_test";
$username_boatshed = "tomzino_user1";
$password_boatshed = "********";
$boatshed = mysql_pconnect($hostname_boatshed, $username_boatshed, $password_boatshed) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```

And the first query in my index.php file is:

```
mysql_select_db($database_boatshed, $boatshed);
$query_getRecordreviewsarchive = "SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(main_table.uploaded, '%M %Y') as recordreviewsarchive, DATE_FORMAT(main_table.uploaded, '%Y-%m') as recordreviewslink FROM main_table WHERE main_table.type = 'Record Reviews' ORDER BY main_table.uploaded DESC";
$getRecordreviewsarchive = mysql_query($query_getRecordreviewsarchive, $boatshed) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getRecordreviewsarchive = mysql_fetch_assoc($getRecordreviewsarchive);
$totalRows_getRecordreviewsarchive = mysql_num_rows($getRecordreviewsarchive);
```

I am afraid I am not very experienced with PHP and SQL but I cannot see where the problem lies.

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: this is a issue with the privileges for this user on this table. You need to use grant command to grant privileges to this user.

Comment: https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/788/HOWTO%3A+GRANT+privileges+in+MySQL#dv

Comment: Is this a legacy application? `mysql_query` is a deprecated method that's being removed from PHP and has no business being in new code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run SELECT in another table, with the same connection parameters.

The command bellow, would give the privileges you need:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database-name.* TO username@'localhost';
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the most important abilities a programmer have to achieve during their career is an **ability to trust their eyes.**

If an error message clearly says that user `'tomzino1_user1'@'localhost'` has no SELECT privilege for the table `'main_table'` - **so it is.** This is the reason and exact explanation for the problem. As simple as that.

Not a guess, nor whatever support team reply doesn't worth a penny against an error message you can observe with your eyes.

So, there is no reason to look for any explanations or reasons - you already have it. Thus, you have to set up the user privileges **properly**.

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

Login in as mysql root user:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

OR

```
mysql -u root -h YOUR_MYSQL_SERVER_ADDRESS -`p
```

Execute command:

```
GRANT SELECT ON tomzino1_boatshed_test.main_table TO 'tomzino1_user1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'YOUR_PASSWORD';
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.

The package I have will not allow root access so I believe I can't do this. I have also checked that the select privilege is selected in mysql user privileges for the relevant database along with all other privileges.